# Clone gihub repository in a new VM

Tags: github, ssh, virtual-machine

I want to be able to clone a private github repository every time I create a new VM. What is the best way to do this?
I have a limitation of using only ssh to clone this repository , since my organization has enforced that upon us. If I create a new ssh key everytime I create the VM I owuld need to register this key with github, which seems like an overkill. If I had to use an existing ssh key pair, I would have to expose it in the VM.
What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: Is that a public or a private repo

Comment: it is a private repo

Answer (score 1):

You can provide credentials while cloning a private repo via command line

`git clone https://username:password@github.com/username/repository.git`

Comment: No I can only usse ssh to clone, besides I dont want username passowrd in plain text anywhere in a script

Comment: Oh I thought you were just connecting to VM with ssh

Comment: Support for password authentication has been removed by GitHub on August 13, 2021. Can you recommend an updated method?